# Latex table goes out of the page

Tags: tables

I have been trying to create a table using the following code but the table is going out of the page (horizontally):

```
\begin{table} [!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
Variable &  No. of Observations & Mean  & Std. Deviation &  Minimum & Maximum\\
\midrule
Unpaid Household Work & 343,59 &    665.55 &    359.82 &    0 & 2820\\
Unpaid Care Work &  343,678 &   128.49 &    211.72 &    0 & 1650\\
Unpaid Domestic Work &  343,706 & 538.43 &  243.05 &    0 & 2130\\
Dependency Ratio &  335,726 &   0.19    & 0.41 &    0   & 18\\
Sex Ratio & 324,363 &   1.43 &  0.99    & 0 &   7.41\\
Monthly Consumption Expenditure (INR) & 344,926 & 12975.12  & 7955.47 & 700 &   131833\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Summary Statistics of All Continuous Variables.}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You use a lot of space to the long texts in the first column. Using a fixed width column, e.g. `p{2cm}` might already help

Comment: (and have a look at the siunitx package to get a proper alignment of your numbers)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you switch from a `tabular` to a `tabularx` environment (with a target width of `\textwidth`), and then (a) allow automatic line breaking in the first column, and (b) abbreviate 4 of the 5 data column headers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
% 'L' column type: suppress full justification, perform hanging indentation
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight \hangafter=1 \hangindent=1em}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [!htbp]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L ccccc @{}}
\toprule
Variable &  No.\ of Obs. & Mean  & St.\ Dev. &  Min. & Max. \\
\midrule
Unpaid household work &  343,59  &  665.55 &  359.82 &  0 & 2820\\
Unpaid care work      &  343,678 &  128.49 &  211.72 &  0 & 1650\\
Unpaid domestic work  &  343,706 &  538.43 &  243.05 &  0 & 2130\\
Dependency ratio      &  335,726 &  0.19   &  0.41   &  0 &   18\\
Sex ratio             &  324,363 &  1.43   &  0.99   &  0 & 7.41\\
Monthly consumption expenditure (INR) & 344,926 & 12975.12  & 7955.47 & 700 & 131833\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Summary statistics of all continuous variables.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```